# How to make custom Quick access in File Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, desktop-customization

In this image, at left side of File Explorer you can see pretty much useful hand of folders.

[image]

Is there anyway to add a custom folder (like Quick access) with custom name and icon and content my self?

My visual studio project path is here.

```
C:\Users\[USER]\source\repos
```

Now I want to have folder named `Visual Studio Projects` with VS icon that shows above content. is that possible in windows 10?

I think I have to tinker registry a little bit but I'm open to any solution. thanks in advance.

**Notice:** I don't want to pin folder into quick access folder. I want an actual custom folder on left side of File Explorer. behind Quick Access, This PC, One Drive, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to add it to the Navigation Pane, you will need to have the following before editing the registry:

A file system folder that contains the data to display to the user.

Name of your cloud service that will appear in the Navigation Pane. This could also be the name of the instance if your service supports multiple accounts.
Identifiable icon for your application.

A CLSID for your application. One way to generate a CLSID for your application is to use the Uuidgen.exe. See CLSID Key for more information about CLSID.
The following steps modify the registry in order to get the necessary information into the File Explorer namespace. The specific steps do three things.

Create keys in the registry for your CLSID that includes values for the name and icon for your extension as well as other information that defines its behavior.
Configure your extension to be integrated into the Navigation Pane in the proper location and with the proper visibility.

You can refer to this guide:

http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/add-custom-folder-this-pc-navigation-pane-windows/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn889934(v=vs.85).aspx