# Is there are any way of customizing Quick Access menu in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Quick Access menu opens every time I open explorer. But there are a lot of useless files, especially in Recent files. If there are any way of customizing it, like excluding files of certain type or files in certain folders?

Comment: Possible answer....https://superuser.com/questions/1265083/how-to-make-custom-quick-access-in-file-explorer?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it easily. In the ribbon interface, you can disable the file or folder from being displayed in quick access.

1. Open **File Explorer**, in **View** tab, choose **Options**.

   [image]
2. Under options, click **Change folder and search options**.

   [image]
3. Locate **Open File Explorer to**, click **This PC** from the drop-down menu.

   [image]
4. In **Privacy** settings, uncheck the following two options, **Show recently used files in Quick access**, **Show frequently used folders in Quick access**. Click **Clear** icon to remove the history data.

   [image]

Comment: I already fixed the problem by moving to Linux, but thanks :)